# Верстка многоуровневого списка

Tags: html, css

Нужно сверстать многоуровневый список с отступами для текста, маркер и номер должны оставаться справа, как на скриншоте.

Не могу сделать, чтобы маркер и номер были прижаты к правому краю всего списка.

Не хотелось бы применять js.

Нужно универсальное решение, потому что неизвестно, сколько будет уровней у списка.

[Ссылка на пример](http://jsfiddle.net/cergey251/srdt0ovp/)

Скриншот:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Убираем `padding-left` у `li` и добавляем возрастающий `padding-left` к каждому следующему блоку `.info`

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/srdt0ovp/3/)

Comment: Нужно универсально решение, т.к. неизвестно, сколько уровней будет. 
http://jsfiddle.net/cergey251/fg4u4whc/

Answer (score 0):

Отрицательный маргин вам поможет. :)

Обновил [ваш пример](http://jsfiddle.net/fenris/srdt0ovp/2/).

Comment: Нет) Вы просто убрали мой паддинг у li.
Мне нужно, чтобы у текста были отступы по уровням, посмотрите скриншот